# Differences between app.shared.module.ts and app.server.module.ts

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am working on an asp.net core 2.0 mvc with angular project. I have created a fresh project from official template;

I can see 2 files in ClientApp subfolder and i do not understand the differences between those 2 files:

```
app.shared.module.ts
app.server.module.ts
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788487/working-with-imports-with-split-app-modules-in-angular4-client-server-share) as I believe it applies to you:

> The ASP.NET Core SPA with Angular 4 template splits the AppModule into three files so that Webpack will be able to efficiently compile the client-side bundle (suitable for running in browsers) and the server-side prerendering bundle (meant for running in Node).
>
> More specifically, such approach expects that:
>
> - browser-specific modules and providers will be put in the app.module.browser.ts file.
> - server-specific modules and providers will be put in the app.module.server.ts file.
> - anything needed regardless of the executing context will be put in the app.module.shared.ts file.